# Mod ability merge should close after prompting "are you sure" instead of forcing the close first

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, merged-questions

Mod ability merge should close after prompting "are you sure" instead of forcing the close first

When you've been modding for a while, sometimes you know that you have two questions that can be merged, for example after a migration. We should be able to have the merge option on an open question prompt you "are you sure you want to close and merge" and then have the close option be inserted automatically as a dupe close in between the merge click and the merge final.

Comment: Agreed; seems like a needless extra step.

Comment: Last time I merged, the question didn't need to be closed. Has this changed recently? I would consider that a good thing: merging is error-prone and cannot be undone, I wish it was restricted to questions that are already closed as uplicates.

Comment: @Gilles if it were defaulted to what you suggest, would I have posted the request?